# Не распечатывается список елементов, хотя xpath задатеся правильный (я проверяю это Xpath Helper )

Tags: selenium-webdriver, print

1. 

[image: список елементов]

List  list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='part-number vis']"));

**// в этой строке я получаю "0", т.е. список пустой и как следствие не получаю список**
System.out.println(list.size());

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {   
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
    }
    Thread.sleep(3500);
    driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Не понятно, какой вы язык используете, на C# это будет так**

```
foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list.Text);
            }
```

Соответственно необходимо убедиться в том, что вы попали в необходимый элемент, информация по [Xpath](https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/xml-tekhnologii/uchitsia-xpath/xpath-kratkoe-rukovodstvo)

Comment: Код я пишу на языке Java